# How to store a collection path for a model?

Tags: generics, design-patterns, data-structures, types, dart

I'm building models for my app in Dart/Flutter. Here's how a model looks like:

```dart
abstract class Model {
  /// A unique identifier of the model.
  /// Gets generated by Firestore.
  final String id;

  Model(this.id);
}

class MyModel extends Model {
  final String name;
  final String description;
  final int order;

  MyModel(String id, this.name, this.items, this.order) : super(id);
}
```

Those models would be stored in Google Firestore in `mymodels` collection:

```
mymodels/abc
mymodels/def
...
```

To fetch a list of these models from Firestore I need to store the collection path (`mymodels`) for `MyModel` type somewhere. So I could use it later when fetching models:

```dart
Future<List<T>> fetchList() {
  // How to know `path` by knowing T?
  _firestore.collection('path').getDocuments()
}
```

Where to store that collection path? I was thinking to declare a static property in `Model` interface, but Dart doesn't seem to allow override static properties.

Would Dart annotations be a good fit for that?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to hardcode in paths, right, and need a place to store the paths, almost like an enum?

Comment: @ThinkDigital that's right

Comment: Got it. Adding an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the best option I've came to is to make `collectionPath` a class member. Here's an example of Repository pattern for Dart/Flutter:

```dart
class FirebaseRepository<T extends Model> extends Repository<T> {
  final Firestore _firestore;
  final String _collectionPath;

  FirebaseRepository(this._firestore, this._collectionPath)
      : assert(_firestore != null),
        assert(_collectionPath != null);

  @override
  Future<List<T>> fetchList() async {
    final snapshot =
        await _firestore.collection(_collectionPath).getDocuments();
    // TODO: Map snapshot documents to [T] and return.
  }
```

Usage:

```dart
final Repository<MyModel> repository = FirebaseRepository(_firestore, 'mymodels');
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to save hardcoded variables that you want to use everywhere and can be used as strings, you can use a class composed of static variables.
Say you have a few collections in firebase.

1. mymodels/modelA
2. mymodels/modelB
3. mymodels/exampleC
4. mymodels/exampleD

You can save these in a class like so:

```
class Path {
    static String modelA = "mymodels/modelA";
    static String modelB = "mymodels/modelB";
    static String exampleC = "mymodels/exampleC";
    static String exampleD = "mymodels/exampleD";
}
```

and then access them in your code and it will resolve to a `String`.
For example: `Firestore.instance.collection(Path.modelA)` can be accessed programmatically and dynamically. As long as the file where this class is created is imported, you can access this anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I understand that is not an option. Please see `Future<List<T>> fetchList()` function in my example. How to lookup the correct collection path within that function *dynamically*?

Comment: @AndreyGordeev you can type check it. I'll update my answer.

Comment: first, What information do you want to use to determine the correct path?

Comment: Just type. `T extends Model`.

Comment: I mean what data do you want to use to calculate it? What variable do you want to use to determine T?

Comment: As I said, just type. My class is a generic class.

Comment: Ok. So you can run 'if (T is ModelA)... Etc

Comment: No, thanks. Sorry, but that is a very bad practice and code smell. Using `if`s or `switch` in this case will lead to providing a default collection path or asserting a case when `T` is not handled by `if`s. There are more clean approaches

Comment: I don't see a way to determining the type without checking using if statements or cases. You're going to have to do it one way or another. You can also store the collection path inside the objects and use them directly.

Comment: ohhh, just read up. You came to that conclusion already :D.It would have been easier to understand if I saw it was part of a class. cause you have to pass T somehow. I get it now